# Ipyparallel error with directview

Tags: ipython, ipython-parallel

When running this code, I have this error :

```
from ipyparallel import error, AsyncHubResult, DirectView as dv, Reference

@dv.parallel(block=True)
def np_std_par(x):
    return np_std(x)

TypeError: unbound method parallel() must be called with 
DirectView instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

How can I use the decorator ?
It sounds unclear.

Answer (score 0):

`dv`, as written in this first code block (and above), is actually not a `DirectView`.

```python
from ipyparallel import DirectView as dv
print(type(dv))
<class 'traitlets.traitlets.MetaHasTraits'>
```

`DirectView` doesn't need to be imported, instead, [it should be created from a `Client()`](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiengine.html#creating-a-directview-instance).

```python
import ipyparallel
client = ipyparallel.Client()
dv = client[:]

print(type(dv))
<class 'ipyparallel.client.view.DirectView'>
```

Now the decorator will perform as expected.  (Although, it looks like you might have to import `np_std` inside your function or use the `require` decorator, but that's another question altogether, I recommend working through the examples in the docs to become more familiar)